# Is there a way to create and display a running total by category in DAX?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am trying to display a running total by category as a stacked bar chart. I have several pieces which are needed for a certain date. My Y-axis represents the number of pieces needed and the X-axis represents the deadlines. As a legend I would like to add the current state of each reference like this:

[image: Categorized running total by date].

I achieved this by creating a column by status and by filling them with 0 and 1 but I would like to find faster way to do so, which would also work if someone added a category.

My need is to see at one glance at which point of the production process are my pieces and at which date they will be needed.

Using a measure I managed to get the running total, which looks like this :

[image: Running total by date]

The current measure is :

```
CALCULATE(
    COUNTA('Historique LOB'[P/N14.Digits]);
    FILTER(
        ALLSELECTED('Historique LOB'[Besoin concaténé format date]);
        ISONORAFTER('Historique LOB'[Besoin concaténé format date]; MAX('Historique LOB'[Besoin concaténé format date]); DESC)
    )
)
```

However when I try to add the state as legend, I get this:

[image: Categorized running total]

I think that the problem is that Power BI calculates the running total on each category. In a way that if after a certain date there is no piece in a given category the category is just not displayed anymore.

I am surprised I couldn't find any help on this anywhere as this can be very easily done on Excel.

I tried "show all the elements without data" without success. I am now looking for a DAX formula to achieve that visualisation. Any idea on the question ?

My data looks like this :

[image: data]

Thank you in advance,

Comment: Please read [ask], then [edit] your question to show a sample of your data, the code you've tried so far, and what your required outcome actually looks like.

Comment: What is your current measure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a separate **Date** table - you could simply use

```
=CALENDARAUTO()
```

Create a relationship between `'Date'[Date]` and `'Table1'[Besoin Concatenee]`.

Now create a measure like:

```
Cumulative Parts = 
VAR DateCurrent = MAX ( 'Date'[Date] )
RETURN
    CALCULATE ( 
        COUNTA ( Table1[Part Number] ),
        FILTER ( 
            ALL ( 'Date'[Date] ),
            'Date'[Date] <= DateCurrent
        )
    )
```

Now create your Stacked Column chart with

`'Date'[Date]` in Axis

`'Table1'[Status]` in Legend

`[Cumulative Parts]` in Value.

Here's an example PBIX file, with some mocked up data: https://pwrbi.com/so_55811631/

[image]

Comment: For other people looking this up in the future, I didnt get it to work: the linked date columns can't have times. I got this working only after I created a seperate column date_notime (for above ex) = INT('Table1'[Besoin Concatenee] ), and linked that instead to the Dat(Date) column.